# Why is Data Not Saved to the Database in my Guestbook Application?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating an application that requires a guestbook..  The data from the database appears on the website however any data I enter from the website doesn't automatically get put into the database.

Here is the code I have..

```
Protected Sub ButSign_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButSign.Click

 Dim strDSN As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & " 
Data source=C:\USERS\SHAUNA WATSON\DESKTOP\PROJECT COPIES\FINAL\APP_DATA\FACTORY.MDF"

 Dim strSQL As String = (((("INSERT INTO Guestbook " & "( Name,Address,Email,Comments)" & "VALUES ('")
 + TxtName.Text.ToString() & " ',' ") + TxtAddress.Text.ToString() & " ', '") + TxtEmail.Text.ToString() & " ',' ") + TxtComments.Text.ToString() & " ')"


    ' set Access connection and select strings 

    ' Create oleDbDataAdapter 
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection(strDSN)

    'Create ole Db Command And call ExecuteNonQuery to execute 
    ' a SQL statement 

    Dim myCmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConn)

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch exp As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", exp.Message)
    End Try
    myConn.Close()
    ' open Thans.aspx page after adding entries to the guest book 
    Response.Redirect("GuestbookThanks.aspx")
End Sub
```

I'm just wondering if anyone can spot something I may have missed!

Comment: Your title conveyed no useful information. I fixed that.

Comment: You are just writing the error to the console, but I doubt you're checking the console since this is ASP.NET. You should log that error, or display it to the user (for testing purposes). Then you'll have the information you seek.

Comment: I look into my crystal ball and I see a file permissions problem. More than likely the user that is running the backend code for the website does not have access to your desktop. You know, security and all. Also, you have a metric ton of parentheses in the line of code that builds your SQL string that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing your code to this:

```
    myConn.Open()
    Dim myCmd As New OleDbCommand
    With myCmd
        .Connection = myConn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Guestbook (Name,Address,Email,Comments) VALUES (@Name,@Address,@Email,@Comments)"
        .Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtName.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtAddress.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtEmail.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@Comments", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtComments.Text
    End With
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConn.Close()
```

Don't put this in a Try Block. If you get an error, just post it, and we'll see what the error is.